# Get fix time for Sonar issue

Tags: sonarqube

When we select sonar issue in SonarQube it gives estimated fix time based on the project rules ( for example 45 mins in the uploaded image)
[image]

Is there a method of getting this value from SonarApi. There is a way to get Technical Debt for whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the API /api/issues/search with the componentKeys and issues parameters then check the "debt" / "effort field where you will find what you are calling "estimated fix time".

Example: https://sonarcloud.io/api/issues/search?componentKeys=org.perf%3Aperf-agent&s=FILE_LINE&issues=AVYSdjCrpi4oK25mkySt